# Rails 4 and jQuery - is it possible to save a model instance using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, model, instance

I am quite new to RoR (new to code in general) and I would like to know if there is any way to save a model instance using a value generated by jQuery, to update an instance attribute without a form.

Example:

show.html.erb:

```html
score: <div id="score"><%= @user.score %></div>

<div class="btn btn-danger play">roll</div>
```

6_s_die.js:

```js
$('.play').on("click", function(){

  var rand = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

  return rand;
  
});
```

Is it possible to use the "rand" variable of the JS once back in the html.erb ?

Or is it possible to append some code in JS to assign rand to user.score and to save user ?

Thank you for any help / tips !

Comment: You can generate random number on click and when it is generated you can directly store by making an ajax call. jQuery only uses elements to update. you can not store direct into DB. you need to use ajax to store values.

Comment: ok thanks I will look into ajax and will update my post when I am able to do it :)

Comment: Okay. let me know If you have any query :)